# What is the difference between a JIRA task and a GreenHopper Technical Task?

Tags: jira, greenhopper

I am getting started with JIRA/GreenHopper to implement my personal Scrum. However, I would like to know the difference between a JIRA task and a GreenHopper Technical Task.

Comment: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/11512/jira-subtask-vs-technical-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Technical tasks are more related to Stories and come in at the planning phase, whereas Task is a relatively generic label that has no external linkage or context.

Comment: That's what I thought it was. Thanks for the confirmation.